# Obtaining a lower bound on probability of an event using expectation of a random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a random variable $0<X<1$ which is a function of a variable $n$. I will denote this random variable by $X(n)$. I have that
$$\mathbb{E}[X(n)]\geq 1-f(n) \,.$$
where $f(n)$ is a another deterministic function of $n$ and $f(n)\in o(1)$, i.e. $f(n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

> I am trying to obtain a lower bound of the form:
> $$\mathbb{P}(X(n)>1-g(n))\geq 1-\varepsilon \,,$$
> for all $\varepsilon>0$, where $g(n)$ is another deterministic function of $n$ (which needs to be found).

My attempt: Since only information about the first moment of $X(n)$ is given, I was thinking of using the Markov's inequality. But that will give me an upper bound:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X(n)>1-g(n))\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X(n)]}{1-g(n)} \,,
\end{align*}
and I am looking for a lower bound. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Try using Markov's inequality for an upper bound on the **complement** of your event.